# char, hex, because it shows ffffff

Tags: c++

I have a *char []*, with the *buffer* name, the data is saved using an ifstream in binary mode,

```
void File::mostrarBuffer(){
  for (int a = 0; a < std::strlen(buffer); a++){
    std::cout << std::hex << ((int)buffer[a]) << std::endl;
  }
  // para ver char test, only for test                                                              
  std::cout <<  "==="  << std::endl;

  for (int a = 0; a < std::strlen(buffer); a++){
    std::cout <<  buffer[a] << std::endl;
  }

  char charTest = '\211';

  std::cout <<  "==="  << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::hex << (int)charTest  << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::hex << (int)buffer[0] << std::endl;
}
```

the shell out:

```
ffffff89
50
4e
47
===
\211
P
N
G
===
ffffff89
ffffff89
```

the file in hexdump ("little-endian"):

```
0000000 5089 474e 0a0d 0a1a 0000 0d00 4849 5244
```

my question is why, appears ffffff89 and not 89, and only on the first element of char [] I've been around with this and can not find the solution. thanks for reading.

**this solution works for me:**

```
 std::cout << std::hex << ((unsigned int)(unsigned char)buffer[a]) 
           << std::endl;
```

Comment: You are using `char` which apparently are *signed* in your compiler, and if the top bit (the sign bit) is set then the casting will do *sign extension*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `char`s are signed (highest bit is set).

I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with using `std::hex` but you somehow need to treat it like an unsigned char value. Try casting the `char` to and unsigned type.

Comment: Casting to `unsigned int` should not change anything unless you cast the `char` to `unsigned char` first.

Comment: Use `std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned int)(unsigned char)buffer[a] << std::endl;`

Comment: `std::hex` is an I/O manipulator: shifting it into a stream changes the base for integer to string conversion to 16.  Since this is a permanent side effect, one should always first shift `std::dec` to convert numbers to decimal representation on output.  There are other such manipulators with the same problem.  This is supposed to replace `printf` formats specs, but it has much worse shortcomings ending somewhere between *hopelessly broken* and *FUBAR*.

Comment: thanks that was the solution, and I think, not that it is more difficult, if adapt to c ++ or ask on stackoverflow, so stupid was the question as to receive your downvotes, you all so much for your time, I do not mean you you've been very kind thanks

Comment: @AngelAngel: There are a couple of things that might have made your question better, but I really do not understand why it was downvoted.

Comment: The question was initially tagged `c`... Die hard C aficionados may be a little quick to down vote

Comment: @chqrlie so much for your time, and your answer

Comment: @chqrlie haha I have three downvotes, but with your speculation "Die hard fans C May be a little quick to down vote" well worth it just gave me laughter.

Comment: The C solution `printf("%02x\n", (unsigned char)buffer[a]);` may not be so *elegant* and type safe, but at least it does not have side effects on `stdout` ;-)